# Asp.net denying direct access to a webpage

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage errors.aspx that needs to be protected from direct access.
I want it to be accessed only when redirected to by another web page.

How can I do it?

Comment: Is the redirect using a `Server.Transfer` or `Response.Redirect`?

Comment: <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Server.Transfer to redirect to the new page, then you can pass a variable in Context collection and check for that in the new page.

Page 1

```
Context.Items.Add("somevar","someval");
```

Page 2

```
if ( Context.Items["somevar"] == null )
{
    // the page is not redirected from Page 1
}
```

Comment: the pages is beeing redirected from customErrors

Answer (score 0):

keep some Boolean value in session and throw an exception from the error page if the value is not set. set the value in the previous page before redirection and that's it

Comment: But when the user tries to open the page in a new tab then this will fail.

Comment: exactly what he want to do, he don't want the user to open it directly.You are right, I think the way you suggests is better but in that case to he should throw exception or something else if the variable doesn't exists

Comment: but I can't set this value on all scenarios, the errors.aspx page is used ase <customerrors>, and redirected by all kind of exceptions.
So if there is an exception there's no way to set the value.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() will return an exception if there is an exception or null I guess in case of direct access, do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` to the `customErrors` tag in web.config. This makes the error redirection like a `Server.Transfer` instead of a `Response.Redirect`. So, if they are at **SomePage.aspx** and an error occurs instead of the URL changing to **MyErrorPage.aspx** it would stay as **SomePage.aspx** but would render the HTML from **MyErrorPage.aspx**. On your **MyErrorPage.aspx** code behind, you could check the `Request.Path` and if it is **MyErrorPage.aspx** that means that someone is trying to directly access the error page. In this case you could do a `Response.End` or whatever else you might want to do at this point to prevent direct access of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Flowing into WebConfig

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.aspx" />
    <add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```